# $ Av=0 $ is $ r(A)<m$ or $ r(A)<n$

Tags: linear-algebra

We now that $ n \times m $ matrix $ A $ and the vector $ v \in R^m $, $ v \neq 0$ $Av=0$. Is $ r(A)<m$ or $ r(A)<n$?

I think since $Av=0 $ has infinitely many solutions then $r(A)<m$ But I am not sure

Update: The question is active and there is no accepted answer

Comment: But it is not explicitly says which one is bigger.

Comment: @Subu The equation $Av = 0$ has a non-zero solution if and only if $r(A) < m$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You are right, I was thinking something else and made that silly error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r(A)$ is the dimension of the column space of $A$. Since $A$ is $n\times m$, $r(A) \leq m$.  Moreover, knowing that $Av=0$ with $v\neq 0$ means that the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent, so the dimension of the column space is less than $m$.

Note that $r(A)$ is also the dimension of the row space of $A$. So $r(A)\leq n$ but we cannot say $r(A)<n$ without additional information.

**example**

$n=2$, $m=3$, $r(A)=2$

\begin{equation}
A = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you clear